# jQuery page pre loader while reloading or changing page

Tags: jquery, preloader

Is it possible in any way that when webpage reloads or opens another page, it will show up a "loding..." graphics (a animated .gif image) instead of going out white and coming back with the new content. Actually I need some way to pass by the default process of page reloading for all browsers through jquery or js. May be this is an abstract idea, but it's just a try to be informed about the reality.

I need this to be active for a few pages of my site. Like the image gallery. when I search the gallery it will reload the whole page changing the title, meta etc. instead of just fetching the new result and replacing the gallery as done generally in AJAX, but the process will be in a decent manner which will provide an illusion of what I described earlier. it will fadeout -> display loading graphics -> fade in with new content. may be it will take a fraction of second to reload and undetectable for high speed internet users but pretty appealing for someone who uses a slower internet.

Comment: Do you want to stop the webpage from reloading entirely, so that you  load new content into the same page, or do you just want to show a loading image while the new page is loading?

Answer (score 0):

You could load with $.ajax your pages but you will encounter several difficulties:

- cross site ajax requests (if needing to request from other domains),
- CSS, and javascript files calling issues,
- SEO issues
- ...

Answer (score 0):

you should consider '#hash mark navigation', where (hash)- links to other pages (or the same page) keep the browers on the same page, and javascript fetches the new content and sticks it into parts of the page where you want, to fill the entire page.

Here's an article that describes this technique: http://www.quintonpike.com/web-development/jquery-url-hash-mark-navigation.html

Comment: Thanks for this idea, but it will hardly help me as I need some js code which will work for an already done website with traditional page reloading method. I have described my idea in a greater details, please have a look, may be there is alternatives. Thanks again for helping us.

Comment: in short, if the browser is asked to load an entirely new page (e.g. by being directed to a new url), there nothing much you can do to prevent the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can not both reload the page, and have a JavaScript running at the same time. So I guess you can go two ways, either you rewrite the code AJAX-style, and never actually reload the page, just replacing the content.

The other way I can think of (that still would give you a small blink as the page is reloaded), but would accomplish somewhat what you are asking for is if you use CSS to hide all elements on the page from the beginning, except from an element that contains your loader. Then you have a JavaScript function that is executed when the onload-event fires, that hides your loader element and displays all your other elements.